# Iterate two arrays and find specific key/value and put into a new single array

Tags: associative-array

I am trying to extract a key and it's value from variable $form_id and place the results into a new variable $the_array.

When I `print("<pre>".print_r($form_id,true)."</pre>");`to the screen is looks like this:

```
<pre>Array
(
  [title] = Contact Us
  [description] =
  [labelPlacement] = top_label
  [id] = 2
)</pre>
"NULL Array"

<pre>Array
(
  [title] = Test
  [description] =
  [labelPlacement] = top_label
  [id] = 3
)</pre>
"NULL"
```

I want new array $the_array to be:

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [title] => Contact Us
    [id] => 2
  )
  [1] => Array(
    [title] => Test
    [id] => 3
  )
)
```

Here is my code:

```
$ii = 0;

foreach ( $form_id as $gf_key => $form_id_value ) {

    if ( $gf_key == 'title' ) { 

        $the_array[$ii] = array( 
            'title' => $form_id['title'],
            'id' => $form_id['id'] 
        );                                      
    }       
    $ii++;              
}
```

but what I get is two arrays:

```
<pre>Array
(
  [0] = Array
    (
      [title] = Contact Us
      [id] = 2
    )
)
</pre>
"NULL Array"

<pre>Array
(
  [0] = Array
    (
      [title] = Test
      [id] = 3
    )
)
</pre>
"NULL"
```

If I echo $ii it increases when iterating the first array in $form_id and then resets back to 0 when it iterates the second array in $form_id.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
function only ($array, $keys) {
  return array_intersect_key($array, array_flip((array) $keys));
}

$the_array[] = only($form_id, ['title', ''id]);
```

If you have multiple form_id's just use loop

Comment: The result is the same as the foreach loop I used. I get back two arrays both with the index set to [0]. See the last example in my description. So yours and my method both produce the same results.

Comment: Is form_id is a array or multi dimension array?

Comment: No, see the first example in my question.

Comment: No matter what I do I can not get the results into a single indexed array.

Comment: Please add only print_r($form_id)  data

Comment: It was different from what you show here. Okay what you want from that array. tittle and all filed id's or field lable and field id?

Comment: I showed the smaller version. I want a single array that is indexed [0], [1] etc. that has "title" => Title 1, "id" => 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111829/discussion-between-vijaykumar-and-jason).